# Using Promises with boolean return values

Tags: javascript, promise, future, boolean-logic

I am interested in the best implementation of a [Promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) that is meant to give a boolean result. My question considers any implementation of Promises / Futures that includes a logical equivalent of `then` as in [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com).
My question is: should such a Promise `resolve` with a boolean whatever the result or should it `resolve` on `true` and `reject` on `false`?

Thus in Javascript as in [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/):

```
class Named {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // always resolve
    isFoo1() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(this.name === 'Foo');
        });
    }
    // resolve or reject
    isFoo2() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.name === 'Foo') {
                return resolve(true);
            }
            reject(new Error('Not Foo!'));
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
const namedObjects = [new Named('Foo'), new Named('FooBar'), new Named('Foo')];
const nameChecks = namedObjects.map(obj => obj.isFoo1());
const checkNames = () => namedObjects.map(obj => obj.isFoo2());

// using always resolve
Promise.all(nameChecks)
    .then(results => {
        if(results.every(v => v)) {
            return alert('all is foo!');
        }
        alert('all is not foo!');
    });

// using resolve or reject
Promise.all(checkNames())
    .then(() => alert('all is foo!'))
    .catch(() => alert('all is not foo!'));
```

I would argue that the "resolve or reject" version works more naturally with the `Promise` concept - in particular using extended implementations as in [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: You can resolve a Promise with *anything appropriate to the application*. Objects, numbers, strings, whatever.

Comment: Note that both versions resolve with bool - the question is not what to resolve with. But whether to map bool to resolve _and_ reject or to bool.

Comment: Sorry, the question still doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to conflate the resolution value of the promise with its state. For example, imagine an XHR query results in `false`. Does that mean there was a rejection, or that the value you queried is actually `false`?

Comment: So you are saying reject if and only if there was an error (in this case when trying to access the name)? Thus arguing for version1?

Comment: @BM, yes, you should use rejection for errors. Though there are people who handle special cases as errors (such as not found errors). My point was merely a general observation of promise implementations, not promise use cases. Promises should not only depend on their fulfill handlers for both states of rejection and fulfillment. They should allow for both by giving each their respective way to deal with the state.

Comment: if you mean "you should use rejection for errors" _and errors only_, then your observation to my understanding would have implications on promise use cases. Specifically it would follow that one should use `isFoo1`.